# Flutter remove OverlayEntry if touch outside

Tags: flutter, dart, drop-down-menu, state-management

I have a `CustomDropDown`, done with a `OverlayEntry`. The problem is that I have a `StatefulWidget` for that, which I place in my Screen simply like that:

```
  CustomDropDownButton(
    buttonLabel: 'Aus Vorauswahl wählen',
    options: [
      '1',
      '2',
      '3',
      '4',
    ],
  ),
```

Now inside that `CustomDropDownButton` I can simply call `floatingDropdown.remove();` where ever I want but how can I call that from a Parent-Widget?? I hope you understand my problem. Right now the only way to remove the `overlay` is by pressing the `DropDownButton` again, but it should be removed everytime the user taps outside the actual overlay.

I am quite lost here so happy for every help! Let me know if you need any more details!

This is the code for my `CustomDropDownButton`  if that helps:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';

import '../../../constants/styles/colors.dart';
import '../../../constants/styles/text_styles.dart';
import '../../../services/size_service.dart';
import 'drop_down.dart';

class CustomDropDownButton extends StatefulWidget {
  String buttonLabel;
  final List<String> options;

  CustomDropDownButton({
    required this.buttonLabel,
    required this.options,
  });

  @override
  _CustomDropdownState createState() => _CustomDropdownState();
}

class _CustomDropdownState extends State<CustomDropDownButton> {
  late GlobalKey actionKey;
  late double height, width, xPosition, yPosition;
  bool _isDropdownOpened = false;
  int _selectedIndex = -1;
  late OverlayEntry floatingDropdown;

  @override
  void initState() {
    actionKey = LabeledGlobalKey(widget.buttonLabel);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      key: actionKey,
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          if (_isDropdownOpened) {
            floatingDropdown.remove();
          } else {
            findDropdownData();
            floatingDropdown = _createFloatingDropdown();
            Overlay.of(context)!.insert(floatingDropdown);
          }

          _isDropdownOpened = !_isDropdownOpened;
        });
      },
      child: Container(
        height: scaleWidth(50),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border(
            bottom: BorderSide(width: 1.0, color: AppColors.black),
          ),
          color: AppColors.white,
        ),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              width: scaleWidth(10),
            ),
            Text(
              widget.buttonLabel,
              style: AppTextStyles.h5Light,
            ),
            Spacer(),
            _isDropdownOpened
                ? SvgPicture.asset(
                    'images/icons/arrow_down_primary.svg',
                    width: scaleWidth(21),
                  )
                : SvgPicture.asset(
                    'images/icons/arrow_up_primary.svg',
                    width: scaleWidth(21),
                  ),
            SizedBox(
              width: scaleWidth(10),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void findDropdownData() {
    RenderBox renderBox =
        actionKey.currentContext!.findRenderObject()! as RenderBox;
    height = renderBox.size.height;
    width = renderBox.size.width;
    Offset? offset = renderBox.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
    xPosition = offset.dx;
    yPosition = offset.dy;
  }

  OverlayEntry _createFloatingDropdown() {
    return OverlayEntry(builder: (context) {
      return Positioned(
        left: xPosition,
        width: width,
        top: yPosition + height,
        height: widget.options.length * height + scaleWidth(5),
        child: DropDown(
          itemHeight: height,
          options: widget.options,
          onOptionTap: (selectedIndex) {
            setState(() {
              widget.buttonLabel = widget.options[selectedIndex];
              _selectedIndex = selectedIndex;
              floatingDropdown.remove();
              _isDropdownOpened = !_isDropdownOpened;
            });
          },
          selectedIndex: _selectedIndex,
        ),
      );
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: I am facing same issue. But I had one more issue that if I navigate to another page then we can override dispose() method as :                                                                                                      `@override
  void dispose() {
    floatingDropDown!.remove();
    super.dispose();
  }` Hope this might be helpful

Comment: Can you share me whole code of this dropdown and its dynamic implementation?

Answer (score 0):

**1. Return a ListView instead GestureDetector**
**2. Under Listview use that GestureDetector containing DropDown as one of the children.**
**3. Add another children(widgets) as GestureDetector and set onTap of each one as:**

```
GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        if(isDropdownOpened){
          floatingDropDown!.remove();
          isDropdownOpened = false;
        }
      },
      child: Container(
        height: 200,
        color: Colors.black,
      ),
    )
```

**In short you have to add GestureDetector to the part wherever you want the tapping should close overlay entry**

** Full Code **

```
//This is to close overlay when you navigate to another screen

 @override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
    floatingDropDown!.remove();
    super.dispose();
  }


Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return ListView(
  children: [
    Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
      child: GestureDetector(
        key: _actionKey,
        onTap: () {
          setState(() {
            if (isDropdownOpened) {
              floatingDropDown!.remove();
            } else {
              findDropDownData();
              floatingDropDown = _createFloatingDropDown();
              Overlay.of(context)!.insert(floatingDropDown!);
            }


            isDropdownOpened = !isDropdownOpened;
          });
        },
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8), color: Colors.orangeAccent),
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0, vertical: 8.0),
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                widget.text,
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
              ),
              Spacer(),
              Icon(
                Icons.arrow_drop_down,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        if(isDropdownOpened){
          floatingDropDown!.remove();
          isDropdownOpened = false;
        }
      },
      child: Container(
        height: 200,
        color: Colors.black,
      ),
    )
  ],
);
```

}

**Let me know whether it helped or not**

Answer (score 0):

Listen to full screen onTapDown gesture and navigation event.

The screen' s gesture event:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RawGestureDetector(
      gestures: {
        PenetrableTapRecognizer: GestureRecognizerFactoryWithHandlers<PenetrableTapRecognizer>(
          () => PenetrableTapRecognizer(),
          (instance) {
            instance.onTapDown = (_) => _handleGlobalGesture();
          },
        ),
      },
      behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
      child: Scaffold(

      ),
    );
  }

  void _handleGlobalGesture {
    // insert or remove the popup menu
    // a bool flag maybe helpful
  }
```

```
class PenetrableTapRecognizer extends TapGestureRecognizer {
  @override
  void rejectGesture(int pointer) {
    acceptGesture(pointer);
  }
}
```